# Do I keep Flare in my Opening Hand Against Mages

Tags: hearthstone

I am playing a Midrange Hunter with one copy of Flare in the Un'goro Meta.

The mages in the Un'goro meta seemingly all have Ice block, and possibly Ice Barrier in their deck.

If I were to keep Flare, it would hard counter an Ice block, allowing me to kill the mage one turn, and possibly two turns earlier.

However, keeping a Flare means I have a dead card in my hand until many turns later, possibly until the last turn of the game. This could delay my killing the mage a turn or more also.

Should I keep flare in my opening hand against Mages?

Comment: What is wrong with this question?

Comment: To close voters: This is a strategy question and [these are explicitly allowed here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Jutschge while the question does fall into the broad category "game strategy", it's extremely opinion-based. We could name dozens of arguments for either keeping or dropping it. There is no right answer except "it depends on your personal preference".

Comment: @scenia there is almost no way an answer to this question is opinion based. It's situational, yes but it doesn't have anything to do with opinions. Also the question describes a specific scenario which can be answered objectively (as you can see with the answers below).

Comment: @Jutschge it's not situational, there's barely any situation to consider at this point in the game. There are 2 answers currently. One gives a huge amount of irrelevant information, then states "I wouldn't suggest keeping it", the other one is full of assumptions. Since the only information about the opponent when making this decision is that they probably run Ice Block, which this card is meant to counter, one could easily argue playing with 1 card less in exchange for guaranteeing the counter when it's needed is the better play. There's no way to give an objective answer here.

Comment: Of course there is an objective answer. The answer is either yes or no. It is a well defined situation, perfectly described. A pro player can certainly answer the question, as they would do one or the other. There is literally almost no strategy question in hearthstone that is less opinion based than this. The question is less opinion based than "Should I keep Golakka Crawler in mulligan against Warrior".

Comment: @scenia: If OP were asking for the best card to counter Ice Block (or any other opponent card), I would agree with you. There is no one right answer. However, OP is asking about a specific card, and whether or not he should try to keep it. This is much more strictly defined; and the answer, while it will always be _somewhat_ opinion based (as most answers are), they can still be justified objectively.

Comment: @Fluidized Well, the current answers rather clearly suggest not keeping it. I happen to hold the opinion that's not correct and can give reasons. It's still an opinion and either answer is perfectly valid. The answer being either yes or no has nothing to do with being opinion-based. For example, "Should Donald Trump be president?" is a yes/no question, and it's entirely opinion-based. The same applies to objectively justifying an answer (@Flater). That has nothing to do with being opinion-based. For reference, here's the definition of opinion-based as per the close vote option (next comment):

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." - Whether to keep a specific card in mulligan is not based on facts, references or specific expertise, but on whether you'd rather take the chance of never drawing it again or play with one card less, which is entirely preferential and thus based on opinion. In contrast, the best counter(s) to Ice Block is clearly a secret-removing card, so naming them all is an objective answer.

Comment: @scenia: "Should Trump be president?" is too broad, you're right. "Can Trump be impeached for [shady action]?" is not. Without self aggrandizing, look at my answer. The majority of my answer are either related facts or well established meta; which influence the keep/mulligan decision. I'm not so much answering with my opinion, but rather listing the pros and cons of either decision and letting OP decide. If we were to only allow questions whose answer is an objective truth (which is what you're arguing here); then why do we have a voting system for _different answers_ in the first place?

Comment: @Flater: It's not too broad, it's opinion-based. This question is not "Can Flare counter Ice Block?" (which would correspond to your impeachment example), it's "Should I keep Flare?". We're supposed to give answers to questions which have strong objective background. Look at my answer. I list related facts, too. I come to an entirely different conclusion. The voting system isn't meant to seperate answers many people agree with from answers few people agree with, it's meant to seperate good answers based on facts from bad answers with objectively false or irrelevant content.

Comment: @scenia the situation to consider is the current meta, what rank he's playing at, and whether it's standard or wild.  You can very accurately predict the type of mage deck based on that info.

Comment: @spudone I know. But even if you know their deck card for card, keeping Flare is an opinion-based choice. I would always argue if he's not keeping a one-of tech against the one matchup it's in the deck for, he might as well play something useful instead. But that's an opinion and other people (as can be seen in the answers) have different opinions. Obviously, the people who don't agree with me on the fact it's opinion-based are also downvoting my well-explained and data-supported opinion because they have a different one, so you can directly see the negative effects.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest success factor (in terms of deck composition) is in the versatility of your deck. You never know what class you'll play against. Ideally, you want a single deck to be able to stand up to different playstyles from different opponents.

That's not to say that each deck, including your own, doesn't have its own weakness to certain other decks. But the key is to try and minimize the amount of decks that you are weak to.

Mages have notoriously tough secrets to get through (they are the class with the most expensive secrets after all). Comparatively, Paladin secrets are a bit annoying but hardly ever a big game changer. Not saying Paladin secrets can't be good (I'm a devout Paladin player), but a random paladin secret will give you less bang compared to a random mage secret (ignoring the different mana cost).

Ice Block, as you mentioned, can turn the tide of a game quickly (or, more accurately, stem the tide of a game that has turned against the mage). Especially if you are playing an aggro deck, every turn counts. If a mage can guarantee stalling you for one more turn, that gives them the freedom to counter your plays without fearing defeat the next turn.

Assuming turn 10+; a mage that played Ice block can spend their next **17 mana** (7 from the turn where they play IB, 10 from the next turn) wiping your advantage off the board. There aren't many boards that can stand up to the equivalent power of a (flamestrike)+(fireball)+(fireball)+(flame cannon). The mage might of course play different cards, but these cards will presumably have a roughly similar bang for buck.
If they play any freezing spell during their 17 mana blowout, this can add another 10 mana per stalled turn.

However, I don't expect a mage to expect a Flare. This means you can catch a cocky mage (who plays balls to the wall because IB is protecting them) and surprise kill them.

It's perfectly acceptable to use the same card differently when playing against a different opponent. This can be based on enemy class (most common) or enemy deck type.

As a mid/control paladin, I keep a Noble Sacrifice in my hand against druids and warriors, but I tend to play it early against a rogue or hunter.

Ice block is a really annoying secret. You can influence the outcome of most secrets (Mirror entity = play a tiny minion; Noble sacrifice = attack with the lowest attack minion first), but Ice block is pretty hard to influence (except for making sure your opponent has the lowest health possible before triggering IB).

I wouldn't suggest keeping Flare in your opening hand if you intend to use it lategame. But I do think it's a valid idea to only want to play the Flare against a seemingly unavoidable Ice Block late in the game.

Comment: Not trying to be mean here, I can see you've put a lot of effort into this answer and that's admirable, but 60% of your answer basically explain why Flare is good in this matchup, which is relevant for including it in the deck, but that's already decided as per the question. The next 30% are about unrelated classes and matchups. The last paragraph is the only thing that's relevant to the question and it contradicts the premise of wanting to use it to catch them off guard since not keeping it means never drawing it again in 2 out of 3 games.

Comment: @scenia OP is asking about keeping a card to counter a specific play. I am not telling OP to roll the dice and hope to redraw the card after mulliganing (which is subjective, as you've been repeating). I am merely stating the consequences of either having a Flare in hand, or **not** having a Flare in hand. It is up to OP to decide how much he wants to avoid not having a Flare in his hand, and how much he thinks the Flare will benefit him in the end. Are you now suggesting that I add my opinion about whether or not to play the odds? Because that would be subjective.

Comment: @Flater the only thing you're saying about Flare is "I wouldn't suggest keeping Flare". Sounds to me like you're telling him to roll the dice. Which is fine, your opinion is required if you want to properly answer the question (which is why the question is opinion-based).

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you run 2 copies, which i would not recommend in the current meta. So I asume you run 1.

Do you play to play it in your first 4 turns? Probably not, since you want flare to get rid of ice-block and kill the enemy in most cases.

I you keep it in your mulligan, you have a useless card in your hand for a looooong time.

You want to draw into it.

I guess an exception could be, you have the coin and a perfect cruve with good minions.

Comment: What would be different if OP ran 2 copies?

Comment: @scenia: I'm not the poster, but trying to comment anyway: when you run two copies, the odds of drawing into this card roughly doubles (it's an oversimplification but accurate enough for the explanation). This dramatically changes whether or not you want to mulligan the card. If it's much more likely that you'll draw it by the time you need it anyway (OP is asking about using it lategame, and will have many draw chances), you will be more inclined to mulligan the card.

Comment: @Flater exactly what I would have written. thank you! Do add something: you could use the first copy to draw a card and destroy any secret. Because normalyy you use flare to specifically get rid of ice-block, which you can still do with a 2nd copy.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW: What you added is completely true, but it seems a bit too unlikely for a player to **base** his strategy on getting the exact card with **one** extra draw (if he drew it earlier anyway, he didn't need the extra draw). It is a good _auxiliary_ chance to win, but not the basis for a strategy, imo :)

Comment: @Flater that's not what I meant

Comment: Let me rephrase that. If the answer in case one copy is run is "mulligan it" (as is the case here), what's different if 2 copies are run? The answer is still "mulligan it".

Comment: @scenia nah. I would keep one in my opening hand if I play agaisnt mage AND run 2 copies I guess...

Comment: I'm confused now. @Flater wrote running two would make him *more* inclined to mulligan it away. You agreed. Now you're saying you'd rather keep it. Wouldn't keeping it when you run two copies not only give you a dead card, but also add the risk of drawing the second one, which is then basically a 2 mana, draw a card Spell, which is also rather bad in this matchup? You want to put so much pressure onto the board you often don't even get to use your Hero Power until the last few turns, paying the same mana for less damage and simply getting a new card is even worse.

Comment: To clear confusion with what I said (maybe for OP) I would **mulligan** the card, but I would **save the card** so I could use it against Ice Block specifically. Two different meanings to the word "keep" in this context :) If I were to run a single copy, I would still mulligan the Flare and choose to save it for Ice Block.

Comment: @scenia there is no write or wrong in hearthstone. Especially when we jsut discuss the mulligan of 1 or 2 cards. you have to play your deck against the opponents deck. so you will get multiple oppinions

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW You only know the opponent's class at this point, so you can't consider the opponent's deck other than by sheer probabilities. There is often a play that maximizes your chances, which can be considered the right play, but the extremely limited information in this specific case means it will always come down to opinion (which is why the question is opinion-based and not a good fit for Arqade). In general, though, there is right or wrong, otherwise it would never matter what you do.

Answer (score -1):

When you're playing Midrange Hunter, your goal is to win the game before reaching the late game, which usually starts around 10 mana. The deck is in essence a fast deck with viable late game options to secure a win even in longer games. The typical win will occurs around **turns 6-12**.

Mage decks tend to lean towards longer games in general. Many of their tools are delaying the game, especially the Ice Blocks. While there are different possible decks, they all aim to stabilize early and keep the board under control until they reach a point where they can get ahead and seal the deal. They will usually attempt to go for the win around the beginning of the late game in **turns 8-15**.

As you can see in this comparison, Hunter is the faster deck most of the time. The correct way to play this matchup to maximize your winning chance is thus to **take the aggro role** and aim for a quick game, while the Mage will take the control role and try to delay the game as much as possible. The main tool for this purpose is Ice Block, and you will want to **counter the Ice Block consistently** because even a single delayed turn might turn your victory into a defeat in this setting.

Mulliganing the Flare (your only Ice Block counter) means there will be a **61-63% chance** (depending on coin) that you **won't draw into it again** by turn 10. By contrast, the Mage has a very high chance of drawing into Ice Block either directly or through Arcanologist and random Spell generation.

The downside of keeping Flare is that you have basically one fewer card in your hand for the entire game (since you'll play Flare in your winning turn). This means you will run out of cards to play more quickly, assuming the game runs long enough. However, Midrange Hunter typically plays a rather high curve, so running out of cards will only happen around turns 8-10 or later. At this point, if you haven't won against the Mage yet, you're in a tough spot anyway.

Since you have no way of getting around Ice Block without Flare and your goal is to win as quickly as possible before the Mage stabilizes and overwhelms you (or draws into his combo, depending on the exact deck), running out of steam is not a concern and you should **keep Flare** so you can end the game on your terms 100% of the time rather than in a measly 38% of games.